# show value in php form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

hello people have to be a form to use all form controls available and after processing all the values ​​show , I have the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Contacto</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nombre = $email = $comment = $consulta = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$nombre = test_input($_POST["nombre"]);
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$evento = test_input($_POST["evento"]);
$consulta = test_input($_POST["consulta"]);
// $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
$evento = test_input($_POST["evento"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

<div class="contenedor">
<div id="encabezado">
</div>
<div id="contenido">
<h1>Como contactarnos</h1>
<h2>Formulario de contacto</h2>
<form id="formulario" class="formulario" action="#" method="post">
<div class="campo">
<label for="nombre">Nombre o razón social: <span>(*)</span></label>
<input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text">
</div>
<div class="campo">
<label for="email">E-Mail: <span>(*)</span></label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text">
</div>
<div class="campo">
Tipo de evento: <span>(*)</span>
<input name="evento" id="evento_empresarial" value="empresarial" type="radio" checked>
<label for="evento_empresarial">Empresarial</label>
<input name="evento" id="evento_particular" value="particular" type="radio">
<label for="evento_particular">Particular</label>
</div>
<div class="interlineado"> <!-- Para alinear esos campos del formulario -->
Me interesa consultar sobre: <span>(*)</span>
</div>
<div class="interlineado">
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_catering" value="catering" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_catering">Catering</label>
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_salones" value="salones" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_salones">Salones</label>
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_musica" value="musica" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_musica">Música</label>
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_fotografia" value="fotografia" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_fotografia">Fotografía</label>
</div>
<div class="campo">
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_decoracion" value="decoracion" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_decoracion">Decoración</label>
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_dj" value="dj" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_dj">DJ</label>
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_show" value="show" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_show">Show</label>
<input name="consulta" id="consulta_videos" value="videos" type="checkbox">
<label for="consulta_videos">Videos</label>
</div>
<div class="campo">
<label for="ubicacion">Zona donde desea el evento: <span>(*)</span></label>
<select name="ubicacion" id="ubicacion">
<option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
<option value="caba">CABA</option>
<option value="gba">GBA</option>
<option value="fueradegba">Fuera de GBA, Bs As</option>
<option value="interior">Interior</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="interlineado">
<label for="comments">Mensaje: <span>(*)</span> </label>
</div>
<div class="mensaje">
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
</div>
<div class="mensaje">
<input name="check" id="check" value="OK" type="submit">
<input value="Cancelar" onclick="$('form')[0].reset()" type="reset">
</div>
</form>
<div id="contacto"> <!-- Otras formas de comunicarse -->
<h2> Contacto </h2>
<div class="campo">
Teléfono:
(0220) 411-1111
</div>
<div class="campo">
Celular: (011) 15-5956-3215
</div>
<div class="campo">
Email: <a href="mailto:user@gmail.com">user@gmail.com</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<?php
echo "<h2>Vos ingresaste:</h2>";
echo $nombre;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $evento;
echo "<br>";
echo $consulta;
echo "<br>";
//echo $gender;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but does not display correctly checkbox displays the first thing I select ; also if I do not select anything shows me a warning , what happens?

Comment: *"shows me a warning"* - being?

Comment: Did you have to post *all* of your code?

Comment: @JohnConde Seems like it; and expecting a *magic* answer to just appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your checkboxes have the same name, but you aren't saving them as an array. What you have to do is change the name in the form to `name="consulta[]"` and then to implode (http://php.net/implode) the array `(implode(',',$_POST['consulta']));` in PHP.

As for the error you are getting it because if no checkbox is checked there is no value passed to PHP yet you are trying to give its value to a variable. Validate your form before sending to prevent users from sending it with no checkbox checked or create an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right...

So first you've got a multiple `name=consulta` for all the checkboxes so in $_POST you will get only the last one that has checked.

Second, you do not need the php function to clear the form, this is enough:

```
<input value="Cancelar" type="reset">
```

And third, you didn't initialize `$evento`